# Secciones a modo de índice

Tags: r

En R (digamos normal, no R-Markdown) en  Code, insert Section, se pueden hacer secciones.

He visto que poniendo un { } puedo meter una sección dentro de otra:

```
# 1.1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
{ # 1.2.1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------}

# 2.1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
{# 2.2 ---------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

Pero no consigo meter más de dos niveles por sección. No puedo meter un 1.2.2 dentro de 1.2.1

¿Hay alguna forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consigues dos niveles, por que estas combinando dos modalidades de "folding", la propia del código (cuando usas las llaves `{}`) y la de "secciones de código" (con los comentarios y al menos 4 `-`, `=` o `#`), pero de todas formas sintácticamente tu código está mal, por que la llave de cierre forma parte del comentario.

Por el lado de las [secciones de código de Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE), te comento que **no soportan anidado**.

Sin embargo, una alternativa, es usar completamente las llaves para definir cada sección y subsección, ejemplo:

```
# 1. Seccion
{ 
  # 1.1 Seccion
  { 
    # 1.1.1 Seccion
    { 

    }
  }
}
```

Pero es importante entender que `{}` es una función de R para agrupar código normalmente como parte de estructuras de control, como `if/else`, o de loop como `for/while`, aunque es tan flexible que puede ser usada de manera individual, en este ejemplo, podríamos decir, de forma decorativa. Ten en cuenta que tiene un costo  ya que se evalúa como cualquier otro tipo de función.